# C# библиотека InstagramApiSharp класс недоступен из-за его уровня защиты

Tags: c#, visual-studio, instagram, instagram-api

пишу на c# с библиотекой InstagramApiSharp

Вопрос такой, в данной библиотеке имеются два класса с модификатором internal, "AccountProcessor" и "UserProcessor", но когда я пытаюсь получить к ним доступ из тела основной программы, то пишет ошибку "недоступен из-за его уровня защиты".

интернет говорит: 
 Класс и члены класса с подобным модификатором доступны из любого места кода в той же сборке, однако он недоступен для других программ и сборок.

с другими классами из библиотеки пока проблем не выявил.
Директивы using подключены.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сюдя по гитхабу эти классы специально скрыты. Вам нужно использовать IAccountProcessor и IUserProcessor.

Comment: Так это же абстрактные классы, их нельзя использовать.

Comment: Это интерфейсы. Почему нельзя? Так обычно делается когда нужно скрыть реализацию.

Comment: Не подскажете, как это сделать?
Можно пример?

Answer (score 0):

```
var requestForEditProfile = await InstaApi.AccountProcessor.GetRequestForEditProfileAsync();
```

[More information](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp/wiki/Account)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]